# pandas merge two dataframes with default value if key missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
                              NAME      base         RED
3                                %      free        2.00
4                                %   freemem        0.10
5                             sys1   freemem        0.20
```

and

```
         NAME
0        sys1
1        sys2
```

There are other columns, which must also exist in the output dataframe, but they don't contain key values, and only one non-key is kept for clarity of description.

I want to merge them together to form permutations of 'base' and 'red' for each value in name. The sticky point is that if a value from df2.NAME appears as a value in df1.NAME, precedence should be given to that row when forming the merge. Otherwise, the values for 'red' should be taken from the row whose name is '%'.

Eg, for the values above, I'd like the output to look like:

```
   NAME     base   RED
0  sys1     free  2.00
1  sys1  freemem  0.20
2  sys2     free  2.00
3  sys2  freemem  0.10
```

I can think how to do this using apply, but it seems like something that should be possible to do with a merge op for better performance.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Create sample
d = dict()
d['name'] = np.array(['%','%','sys1'])
d['base'] = np.array(['free','freemem','freemem'])
d['red'] = np.array([2,0.1,0.2])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1 = df1[['name','base','red']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['sys1','sys2']),columns=['name'])
################################################
part1 = df1[df1['name']!='%']
part2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df2.values:
    copy = df1[df1['name']=='%'].copy()
    copy['name'] = np.repeat(i,len(copy['name']) )
    part2 = part2.append(copy)
'''
Part 1:
   name     base  red
2  sys1  freemem  0.2

Part 2:
   name     base  red
0  sys1     free  2.0
1  sys1  freemem  0.1
0  sys2     free  2.0
1  sys2  freemem  0.1
'''
ans = pd.merge(part1,part2, how='outer')
        .drop_duplicates(['name','base'])
print ans.sort_values(['name', 'base'], ascending=[True, True])
Out[]:
   name     base  red
1  sys1     free  2.0
0  sys1  freemem  0.2
3  sys2     free  2.0
4  sys2  freemem  0.1
```

Since `pd.merge(part1,part2, how='outer')` would put `part1` above `part2` and the apply `drop_duplicates()` would remove the repeated values in `part2`.
It's not the simplest way, but it works. Hope it can help.

Comment: @user3662805 can my solution above solve your question?